# How to prove $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}$ is decreasing.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I need to prove this before I can use the Integral Test to determine if the series is is converging or diverging. My series is from [1,infinity).
I tried plugging in number and the function seems to increase, so I tried the derivative and now I'm stuck.

Thank you, everyone!
I've got it now.  The original problem was to determine if the series converges or diverges and why.
Series was from n=1 to infinity: (ln n)/(sqrt n)

Comment: The sequence certainly isn't decreasing everywhere -- the value at $x=1$ is $0$; whereas at $x=4$ it is $\ln 2$, which is larger than $0$.

Comment: It would be useful to know what the original problem is, so that one can see whether the fact that the function is soon decreasing is enough.

Comment: An useful reduction:Replace $x=y^2$, and we have $2ln(y)/y$ is decreasing iff $ln(y)/y$ is iff $\sqrt[y]{y}$ is.It is now easier to derivate and show a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

The derivative is equal to $$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\log x}{x}=\frac{1- \frac{1}{2}\log x}{x\sqrt{x}}.$$ So, it is enough to show that if $1-\frac{1}{2}\log x\leq 0$ then the function is decreasing.

Equivalently, $\log x\geq 2$. So, for $x\geq e^2$, the function is decreasing, on $[e^2,\infty)$.

Comment: Do you mean ln x instead of log x?

Comment: @user101335 The notation $\log x$ is often used for the natural logarithm in mathematical context, for example on WolframAlpha.